# How to embed a Gist within a GitHub issue comment?

Tags: github, gist

I have a Gist that I would like to embed within a GitHub issue. I have tried pasting the "Embed" `<script>` markup shown on the Gist page, which simply adds the *escaped* HTML to the issue comment.

This seems a rather obvious feature to not be supported. What am I missing?

Comment: I think at the moment the best thing you can do is to put a link.

Comment: @mcsim is there any tricks like user/repo#id patterns to auto link?

Answer (score 4):

Because embedding requires a `<script>` tag which gets sanitized and removed to prevent abuse this probably won't ever work in GitHub Issues.